# How can I check if all the images in list are stored in firebase storage or not in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagesUriList.size(); i++) {
        Uri uri = imagesUriList.get(i);
        StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child("Images/" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        imageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                imageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String fileUrl = uri1.toString();
                        }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have written this code for uploading list of images in firebase. Now I do not know how to check if all images are uploaded in firebase storage or not. Any suggestions about how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your onFailure triggered? Did you get any errors?

Comment: yes I have added the onfailure code.

Comment: Is the code inside onFailure triggered?

Comment: I simply want to check if all images in list are uploaded or not in firebase?